# How to add data to a dictonary in c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

How to add data to dictonary from xml file

scenerio:

I've declared a dictonary like

```
 Dictonary<string,string> SampleDict=new Dictonary<string,string>();
```

and my xml file is like

```
 <Data>
   <Element ValOne="1" ValTwo="0" />
   <Element ValOne="2" ValTwo="2" />
   <Element ValOne="3" ValTwo="4" />
   <Element ValOne="4" ValTwo="6" />
   <Element ValOne="5" ValTwo="8" />
   <Element ValOne="6" ValTwo="10" />
   <Element ValOne="7" ValTwo="12" />
   <Element ValOne="8" ValTwo="14" />
   <Element ValOne="9" ValTwo="16" />
   <Element ValOne="10" ValTwo="18" />
</Data>
```

i need to read the value of "ValOne" and "ValTwo" using LINQ and insert the same into the above declared dictonary

and how to add the contents of the dictonary to a listview which contains two columns.

Please help me to do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems already discussed similar one on forum [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015773/how-can-i-load-the-following-xml-using-linq-to-xml-into-a-dictionary)

Comment: Please clarify / retag your question appropriately: are you referring to a ListView in WPF? ASP.NET? WinForms?

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary and not writing a function for what appears to be a simple mathematical operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Linq to XML and ToDictionary for this.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path to xml");
doc.Elements("Element").ToDictionary(
  elem => elem.Attribute("ValOne").Value, //Dictionary key
  elem => elem.Attribute("ValTwo").Value  //Dictionary value
);
```

This particular overload of [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) uses different lambdas to extract keys and values for the generated collection.

Comment: I think MasterGaurav provides an adequate solution to the question of binding the data to a listview.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you want ValOne to be the key and ValTwo to be the value?

```
document.Descendants("Element")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(e => SampleDict[e.Attribute("ValOne").Value] = e.Attribute("ValTwo").Value);
```

This assumes you have read your XML file into an `XDocument` or `XElement`

Answer (score 1):

```
XElement allData = XElement.Load("File.xml");
var els = allData.Descendants("Element");

foreach(var xe in els)
{
   SampleDict[xe.Attribute("ValOne").Value] = xe.Attribute("ValTwo").Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use data binding in that case. Have a look at this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/DBListViewForV2.aspx

All you need to do is...

```
var items = from xe in els
  select {
    ValOne = xe.Attribute("ValOne").Value,
    ValTwo = xe.Attribute("ValTwo").Value
  }

var arr = items.ToArray();

//private DBListView dataBoundListView;
//dataBoundListView.DataSource = this.bindingSource1;
this.bindingSource1.DataSource = arr;
```